# is there anyway to apply two transform property to same element

Tags: html, css, web, sass, frontend

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--1">
    <img src="img/gal-1.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 1" class="gallery__img" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--2">
    <img src="img/gal-2.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 2" class="gallery__img" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item gallery__item--3">
    <img src="img/gal-3.jpeg" alt="Gallery image 3" class="gallery__img" />
  </figure>
</section>
```

The functionality i want is when i hover one of the image i want that image to scale(1.1) and other image to scale(0.9) only using css.

The code that i tried was:

```css
.gallery {
  &__img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  &__img:hover &__img:not(:hover) {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
}
```

but it's not working.

Comment: `.gallery:has(img:hover) img { transform: scale(0.9); }`, then the regular hover one

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this ?

```css
figure {
  display : inline-block;
  margin  : 0;
  padding : 1em;
  }
.gallery:hover img {
  transform: scale(.9);
  }
.gallery figure:hover  img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  }
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/200?random=1" alt="Gallery image 1" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/200?random=2" alt="Gallery image 2"/>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/200?random=3" alt="Gallery image 3" />
  </figure>
</section>
```